# wso2 Api management configure corporate proxy

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I managed to get wso2-AM to work on my local machine.
However, I can't integrate an API if it's only reachable using a corporate proxy.

I got a tomcat application HTML page when I try to invoke the API.

```
ERROR - APIProviderHostObject Error occurred while connecting to backend : https://mypage.mydns:8443/oidc-client/, reason : The host did not accept the connection within timeout of 4000 ms
```

Of course from the host that runs the server I can do a

```
wget https://mypage.mydns:8443/oidc-client/
```

and it works.

However, when I do it without proxy set in the environment variable

```
wget --no-proxy https://mypage.mydns:8443/oidc-client/
```

I get a timeout.

My question is, how do I configure wso2 AM to use a corporate proxy to access a remote backend.

Thanks for any clue.

If I find a way, I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following system parameters to wso2server.sh with your proxy settings.

```
-Dhttps.proxyHost='10.46.12.63' \ 
-Dhttps.proxyPort='3128' \ 
-Dhttp.proxyHost='10.46.12.63' \ 
-Dhttp.proxyPort='3128' \ 
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="127.0.0.1,localhost,*.wso2.com" \
```

Comment: I edited the file, i got the parameter updated in the launched process
 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Xbootclasspath/a: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt/wso2/repository/logs/heap-dump.hprof -Dhttps.proxyHost=myproxy -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.noProxyHosts=127.0.0.1,localhost ...
however still the same issue
and i can telnet myproxy 8080.
It's working on your side ?

Comment: Can you try adding them to axis2.xml as well ?
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Production+Deployment+Guidelines#ProductionDeploymentGuidelines-Commonguidelinesandchecklist

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer again, there is a typo in the documentation : 
"configuration" has not the same case when the tag is oppened or closed. 
I tried with "configuration" and "Configuration", and i still got the timout. 
Maybe this configuration does not work anymore. I'm really sorry for not finding this documentation, i could have tried myself